# Wrong store ID generates errors in Magento backend

Tags: magento

When going to System>Config.>Developer I get this stack, which seems to have something to do with store id 4. I once had a store with Id 4, but it's deleted and I only have store id 1 now. I cannot figure out what is calling this store id4, only that it is called since " Mage_Core_Model_Url->setStore('4')" is in th stack. How can I tell, what extension, module or part of Magento that is calling this?

```
#0 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(831): Mage_Core_Model_App->throwStoreException() 
#1 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(342): Mage_Core_Model_App->getStore('4') 
#2 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(616): Mage_Core_Model_Url->setStore('4')
#3 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(734): Mage_Core_Model_Url->setRouteParams(Array, false) 
#4 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php(977): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getRouteUrl('', Array) 
#5 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(362): Mage_Core_Model_Url->getUrl('', Array) 
#6 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Magentohotel/Varnish/Model/Adminhtml/Renderer/Bans/Categories.php(31): Mage::getUrl('', Array) 
#7 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(421): Magentohotel_Varnish_Model_Adminhtml_Renderer_Bans_Categories->toOptionArray(true) 
#8 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php(210): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initFields(Object(Varien_Data_Form_Element_Fieldset), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element)) 
#9 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Edit.php(92): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form->initForm() 
#10 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php(102): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Edit->initForm() 
#11 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Adminhtml_System_ConfigController->editAction() 
#12 /var/www/site.com/public_html/var/cache/extendware/ewcore/overrides/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard/63563f9ebb198e3182fd11a84369b608.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('edit') 
#13 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_StandardOverriddenClass->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#14 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(348): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /var/www/site.com/public_html/app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#16 /var/www/site.com/public_html/index.php(83): Mage::run('', 'store') #17 {main}"
```

Comment: I see that you have an extension called `Magentohotel_Varnish`. Try to disable that and see if the error reproduces. If not...at least you isolated the problem a bit.

Comment: If I disable the module, the error goes away - so far so good, maby some conflict? I just cannot see what it should be conflicting with

Comment: I'm shooting in the dark here, but, most probably there is a problem in this piece of code `Magentohotel_Varnish_Model_Adminhtml_Renderer_Bans_Categories->toOptionArray`. Maybe this reads some config setting that was saved back when the store `4` existed, and now it tries to do something with that. Also check the `core_store` table to see if there is a record with ID 4 in it. If there is delete it, but back-up first.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Marius - Your information got me on track, the categories.php had an array that involved some url-rewrites, and the old rewrites from Store Id 4 was still in the database, removing them solved the problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old URL Rewrites fom another storefront was still in the database, this created errors with a varnish module that could see the URL rewrites but not the storefront with the same ID.